# ASUS Vivobook Flip 14 TP412 touchpad and keyboard does not work

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad, asus

On my **ASUS Vivobook Flip 14 TP412**, the touchpad and keyboard do not work.

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 with libinput (`1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1`).

What makes the whole thing so strange is that the keyboard and touchpad work with an old Windows (e.g. Windows XP) or an old Ubuntu (e.g. Ubuntu 18.04).

I have already asked for help on the libinput project: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/issues/840

They said that this is probably a kernel problem. When I read here https://www.kernel.org/category/contact-us.html that I should contact askubuntu, I thought I should ask the same question here.